# MYSQL Usar IF THEN ELSE sin crear un procedimiento

Tags: mysql

Ésto sería ideal para mí:

```
SET @aborta = 0;

SET @aborta = (SELECT id FROM una_tabla WHERE campo=1 LIMIT 1);

INSERT INTO otra_tabla (nombre) VALUES ('prueba') WHERE @aborta = 0;
```

...pero ya sabemos que la cláusula `WHERE` no funciona con `INSERT INTO`.

Otra opción es usar `IF THEN ELSE`:

```
SET @aborta = 0;

SET @aborta = (SELECT id FROM una_tabla WHERE campo=1 LIMIT 1);

IF @aborta = 0 THEN

   INSERT INTO otra_tabla (nombre) VALUES ('prueba');

END IF;
```

Sin embargo para usar este código me veo obligado a crear un procedimiento almacenado `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Existe alguna forma de usar los condicionales directamente en las instrucciones?

Con la función `IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)` no puedo ejecutar el `INSERT INTO`. No me funciona:

```
SET @aborta = 0;

SET @aborta = (SELECT id FROM una_tabla WHERE campo=1 LIMIT 1);

IF ( @aborta = 0, INSERT INTO otra_tabla (nombre) VALUES ('prueba'), '' );
```

Gracias !!

Comment: Pro tip: "No me funciona" es una pésima descripción de un error. Normalmente hay un mensaje, traza, comportamiento inesperado, etc.

Comment: Lo que quería decir es que no lo reconoce: Algo raro en la sentencia.....  ```SELECT IF( @abort=0, INSERT INTO tabla (nombre) VALUES ('prueba') );```

Comment: No lo reconoce _quién_? Ves que hay cosas de la pregunta que ponen a adivinar a la gente? De nuevo, si hablas de la BD, significa que probaste la consulta y sale un error. Si hablas de un editor o IDE, te debe dar un mensaje en la validación, etc. Y lo último, mysqli no es lo mismo que mysql. EL primero es una librería de PHP para conectarse a mysql... pero encontraste la solución y eso es lo importante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sentencia `INSERT` también "acepta" el resultado de un `SELECT`; cuestión que el `SELECT` regrese vacío (sin filas) o no según requieras.
Con los datos que proporcionas prueba con lo siguiente; y ajustas a tu escenario real/total:

> Tomando tu primer referencia de sentencias SQL de tu planteamiento.

```
INSERT INTO otra_tabla (nombre) 
SELECT 'prueba' FROM una_tabla WHERE campo=1 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tomando como referencia la respuesta de RobertoLeOr (muchaaaas graciaasss!) la solución quedaría así:

```
SET @aborta = 0;

SET @aborta = (SELECT id FROM una_tabla WHERE campo=1 LIMIT 1);

INSERT INTO otra_tabla (nombre) SELECT 'prueba' FROM DUAL WHERE @aborta = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si esté mal, me parece que llegue a ver algunos inserts con un query de consulta, algo como:

```
INSERT INTO *tabla* SELECT * FROM *tabla*;
```